# adding more Values in kivy window and getting the result in new Label in the same Window , dynamic array

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic, kivy, screen

I am new to Kivy and need your help. I have a small question:

I need a dynamic array, in which the user can enter the first value in the first TextInput field, then he can press the "New line" button, he gets the opportunity to enter the second value in a new TextInput field as he can press again The "New Line" button gives him the option of entering a third value in the new TextInput field. With "Result" he can call up the sum of these values in a label at any time

How can I create this dynamic array? Thank you very much

this is my main.py file

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_file('MyMain.kv')
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.counter = 1
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_stuff)

    def add_stuff(self, *args):
        self.textlist = [TextInput()]
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value {}'.format(self.counter)))
        self.counter += 1
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[0])

    # function to create new inputs, that button 'new line' calls:
    def addnewtextinput(self):
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value ' + str(self.counter)))
        self.counter += 1
        self.textlist.append(TextInput())
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[-1])

    # function to get a result:
    def getresult(self):
        result = 0
        for i in self.textlist:
        # you may convert it to float if you need, like float(i.text)
            result += int(i.text)
        self.ids.label_id.text = str(result)


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b1=WindowManager()
        MainWindow()
        return b1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

this is MyMain.kv

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 40

<WindowManager>:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    # don't forget to add this
    grid: grid.__self__

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        # you will control that GridLayout from .py so here it's empty
        GridLayout:
            # set the id to be able to control it from .py file
            id: grid
            cols: 2

        CustButton:
            text: "new line"
            on_press: root.addnewtextinput()

        CustButton:
            text: "result"
            font_size: "30sp"
            on_press: root.getresult()

        TextInput:
            id:label_id
            font_size: 40
            multiline: True
```

i cant see the kivy Window .. can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some wrong things in your code, but what you need to do to run this is:

- First, change the root widget `WindowManager:` to a rule `<WindowManager>:` and
- Second, add things when the widget is finished initializing, using `Clock.schedule_once(self.add_stuff)`.

The `.py` should look like this:

```py
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.counter = 1
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_stuff)

    def add_stuff(self, *args):
        self.textlist = [TextInput()]
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value {}'.format(self.counter)))
        self.counter += 1
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[0])

    # function to create new inputs, that button 'new line' calls:
    def addnewtextinput(self):
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value ' + str(self.counter)))
        self.counter += 1
        self.textlist.append(TextInput())
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[-1])

    # function to get a result:
    def getresult(self):
        result = 0
        for i in self.textlist:
        # you may convert it to float if you need, like float(i.text)
            result += int(i.text)
        self.ids.label_id.text = str(result)


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b1=WindowManager()
        MainWindow()
        return b1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi noEmbryo
thanks for your answer, i don't quite understand your sentence " add things when the widget are finished initializing using Clock.schedule_once(self.add_stuff). "
should i add it in the .kv file ?

Comment: @jan Rephrased it in my answer. What I mean is, that you must first let a widget finish its initialization (run the `init` method), and then add some widgets to it. When you schedule something, it gets executed in the first available moment (after `init`). The fixed `.py` includes this call.

Comment: the problem i can't arrive to the .KV file ,form the file .py
the module "Builder" is not activated , and i have this Error : "line 20, in add_stuff
     self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value {}'.format(self.counter)))
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'"

Comment: @jan Glad to hear it. So you can [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)...

Comment: I have to make small change to the task:
instead of that, the User has to write different values in the 1st textinput "1st input Values" and dot"." between each value,e.g. 9.2
if He press Enter, you get the possibility to create a new box, "2nd input values"
and then he can continue to write the values in the 2nd box, e.g.1
then He can press "Result", He get the sum in 2 different labels
1st value from the 1st box "9" plus 1st value from the 2nd box "1"
2nd value from the 1st box "2" plus 2nd value from the 2nd box "0"
how can i make this Dynamic Array in the Box ? 
Thanks

Comment: I have to make small change to the task:
instead of that, the User has to write different values in the 1st textinput "1st input Values" and dot"." between each value,e.g. 9.2.7 if He press Enter, you get the possibility to create a new box, "2nd input values"
and then he can continue to write the values in the 2nd box, e.g.1.3
then He can press "Result", He get the sum in 3 different labels.
1st value in 1st box "9" + 1st value in 2nd box "1"
2nd value in 1st box "2" + 2nd value in 2nd box "3"
3rd in 1st Box "7" + 3rd in 1st Box "0"
how can i make this Dynamic Array in the Box?
Thanks

Comment: @jan If you want something more than what is already asked, it would be better for everyone reading, that you create a different, new question.

Answer (score 0):

Answering as to why you can't see anything:

If you want to automatically load your kv file without calling Builder.load_file then you need to make sure the name of your kv file is the name of your App class minus the App part.

For instance in your case, your kv file should be named mymain.kv not main.kv

to load the kv file manually please use builder

```
Builder.load_file('main.kv')
```

Please see https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html for more help.

After this NoEmbryos answer should get you the rest of the way.
Hope that helps!